# Returning multiple PHP echo value to JQuery ajax in multiple textfields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my Php File in which I will return two echoes via jquery ajax

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data1'];
$data2="h";
if($data2==$data)
{
 echo "john";
 echo "usa";
}
else
{
 echo "Error";
}
?>
```

This is where I call it with ajax and set the name and location to text fields

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="location">
<button id="submit">Click</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var a = "h";
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    data1: a
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now I want that John will display in the name field and the USA will display in the location field

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: fill your value in array and then encode array with json. on client side decode it and set value in field.

Comment: You are just echo the "john" . Have you tried 
return "john usa";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should echo `json array` as:

```
<?php
    $data=$_POST['data1'];
    $data2="h";
    if($data2==$data)
    {
     echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John", "country"=> "usa"));die;
    }
    else
    {
     echo "Error";
    }
    ?>
```

and parse json response in ajax as:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="location">
<button id="submit">Click</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var a = "h";
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    data1: a
                },
                success: function(response) {
              var respData = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#name').val(respData.name); // set name
                $('#location').val(respData.country);// set country name
                    //alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.parseJSON(...).$ is not a function
    at Object.success (test1.php:31)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: or you can use JSON.parse(json);

Comment: I'm using Jquery 3.2.1

Comment: use this var respData = JSON.parse(response)

Answer (score 0):

It simple you can try this code. json_encode method useful for send multiple value through array.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json');
$data=$_POST['data1'];
$data2="h";
if($data2==$data)
{

echo json_encode(array('john', 'usa'));
}
else
{
echo json_encode(array('Error'));

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
data:{
     data1: a
},
```

With

```
data:{
     'data1': a
},
```

And make field in your html like this

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="location">
<button id="submit">Click</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and change

```
echo "john";
 echo "usa";
```

with

```
echo "<div>john</div>
<div>usa</div>";
```

And change

```
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

With

```
 success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is about using the output, not an issue with the input

Comment: I need to show the output in two text-fields not in a div like result

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to return your params as JSON then parse those using javascript.

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data1'];
$data2="h";
if($data2==$data)
{
 echo json_encode(array(
  "name"=>"john"
  "country"=>"usa"
 ));
}
else
{
 echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Then update the input

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var a = "h";
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    data1: a
                },
                success: function(response) {
                   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response).
                   $('#name').val(data.name);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.parseJSON(...).$ is not a function
    at Object.success (test1.php:31)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
success @ test1.php:31
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ test1.php:23
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: @Ankrish Try jQuery.parseJSON() instead of $.parseJSON. I will update my answer